# Can Mallat's pyramidal algorithm be extended to non-power of 2 input sizes?

Tags: signal-processing, wavelet

Mallat's pyramidal algorithm for the discrete wavelet transform operates on power-of-2 vector lengths. Can it be extended to work on inputs of any size without resorting to zero padding?